# Need to support reading from two IBM MQ's

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

`
@EnableJms

@Slf4j

@Configuration

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.abc.efg")

public class MessageConfig {

```
@Value("${spring.ibmmq.host1}")
private String host1;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.host2}")
private String host2;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.port1}")
private Integer port1;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.port2}")
private Integer port2;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.queuemanager1}")
private String queueManager1;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.aaa.queuemanager2}")
private String queueManager2;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.channel}")
private String channel;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.queuename1}")
private String queueName1;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.queuename2}")
private String queueName2;

@Value("${spring.ibmmq.sslciphersuite}")
private String sslCipherSuite;


@Bean
@Primary
public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactoryA() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host1);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager1);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port1);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("Failed in connection establishment" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}
@Bean
public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactoryB() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host2);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager2);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port2);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("Failed in connection establishment" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer queueContainerA() {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactoryA());
    container.setDestinationName(queueName1);
    container.setMessageListener(getListenerWrapperA());
    container.start();
    return container;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer queueContainerB() {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactoryB());
    container.setDestinationName(queueName2);
    container.setMessageListener(getListenerWrapperB());
    container.start();
    return container;
}

@Bean
public MQListenerA getListenerWrapperA() {
    return new MQListenerA();
}
@Bean
public MQListenerB getListenerWrapperB() {
    return new MQListenerB();
}
```

}
`need to support reading from 2 queues, there is a primary and secondary, need to do that automatically in case the sender switches, which queue they use we won't have to do anything.
the queue managers are on the same host for this we have to listen to both.

Comment: Your question suggests you need to read from 2 queues and then  later it suggests you need to read from 2 queue managers. Can you clarify. Is this the same named queue on two different queue managers, or two different queues on one queue manager?

Comment: I need to read from two queue for the fault tolerance purpose both the queues are on the different queue managers and on the same host.

Comment: Having both queue managers on the "same host" is not a design for fault tolerance.  It's just a waste of resources.

Comment: Do both queues have the same name? Also, please update your question with these extra details.

Comment: @Roger A correction the queue Managers are on different hosts

Comment: @MoragHughson both the queues have same name but queuemanagers and hosts are different

Comment: its not working with both queueContainer A & B but works  only with A

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just one, you would need to set up two beans in your Spring configuration with JMSListeners using different configurations (ConnectionFactory / Destination).

Before doing so, you may want to suggest a redesign of your solution. There is a comprehensive chapter called "High availability configurations" in MQ documentation. Select the one which best fits to your requirements. Afterwards, there is a good chance you don’t need to listen to two queues in parallel anymore.

Comment: I update the code here but this code throwing error for queuecontainerB i.e. second listener container.Its not able to create queuecontainer. is there anything I am missing in the code.

Comment: What exception (mq reason code) do you get? Is the "aaa" in spring.ibmmq.aaa.queuemanager2 added on purpose?